# What's wrong with this script and why am I getting no error?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

So I'm relatively new to JS and decided to practice a bit. I wanted to make a webpage to select how many products you want to buy, with two buttons a plus and a minus. The program was supposed to add 1 to an input or take 1 depending on what button was impressed. [image of webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XylGn.png)

So that worked fine but then I added an if statement to make sure the user didn't enter above 4 tickets or lower than 0 tickets. This produced nothing and in developers tools on chrome it just flashes an error but doesn't keep it there. Any help would be appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <style>
 .myButton {
  background-color:#44c767;
  -moz-border-radius:28px;
  -webkit-border-radius:28px;
  border-radius:28px;
  border:1px solid #18ab29;
  display:inline-block;
  cursor:pointer;
  color:#ffffff;
  font-family:Arial;
  font-size:17px;
  padding:16px 31px;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #2f6627;
 }
 .myButton:hover {
  background-color:#5cbf2a;
 }
 .myButton:active {
  position:relative;
  top:1px;
 }

 </style>
 <script>

 function plus(){
 document.getElementById("htop").value=Number(document.getElementById("htop").value)+1;

 }
 function minus(){
 document.getElementById("htop").value=Number(document.getElementById("htop").value)-1;

 }
 function validate(){
  if(Number(document.getElementById("htop").value)<=0){
   alert("You can not submit less than NULL tickets");
   return false;
  }
  else if(Number(document.getElementById("htop").value)>4){
  alert("you can not buy more than 4 tickets at once");
  return false;
  }
  else{
   alert("you may proceed");
   return true;
  }
 }

 </script>
</head>
<body >
 <form>
 <button id="plus" class="myButton" onclick="plus()">+</button>
 <button id="minus" class="myButton" onclick="minus()">-</button>
 <input type="text" id="htop" value="0" />
 <br>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validate()">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `onclick="return validate()"`. since you're not aborting the form submission properly, you end submitting to yourself, and end up with a "new" clean page.

Comment: Still getting the same problem!

Comment: and note that button tags within a form will also submit the form, so you need to put some abort-the-submission stuff there too

Answer (score 1):

I believe that with what you are trying to do, you should not use form tags. Try removing those.

```
<body >
    <button id="plus" class="myButton" onclick="plus()">+</button>
    <button id="minus" class="myButton" onclick="minus()">-</button>
    <input type="text" id="htop" value="0" />
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validate()">


</body>
```

Comment: I did and I think your right! out of interest, why does that happen when in the form tags?

Comment: Form tags need `onsubmit`. But if you do this, it would call this function every time you click one of the buttons, which is not what you want. Form tags are best used when you have a lot of text areas, radio buttons, or checkboxes.